# Cast List<MyType> to Class that extends List<MyType>

Tags: c#, list, casting

Here's the problem

I'm trying to cast form List to an object MyTypes which is defined as

```
public class MyTypes : List<MyType> { ... }
```

It won't cast directly with (MyTypes) - **compiler error**

Or with *as MyTypes* - **returns null**

I would think this would be possible, but clearly I have to overload some casting operation.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your `List<MyType>` in as a parameter when constructing your `MyTypes` and then hand this off to the base class constructor..

Comment: That's what I resorted too when I realized what I wanted was impossibel

Comment: Eric Lippert writes about this kind of thing on his blog, and I'm sure he has covered this but I can't find the article at the moment, apologies. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If MyTypes inherits from List you cannot cast a List if MyType.

Example this is not valid:

```
MyTypes foo = new List<MyType>();
```

This is valid:

```
List<MyType> foo = new MyTypes();
MyTypes bas = (MyTypes) foo;
```

You cannot cast a base class isntance to an inherited type, example, you cannot cast from Vehicle to Car but you can do it from Car to Vehicle (If Car : Vehicle)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a `List<MyType>`, and you want to cast it to a `MyTypes`, which derives from (inherits) from `List<MyType>` ...

You can't do this... If you had a `MyTypes` you could cast it *up* the imnheritence chain to a `List<MyType>`. But you can't cast *down* the inheritence chain...